# Missing templates in Visual Studio Community 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have installed several vsix extensions but when I add a new project none of them are displayed.  I have tried closing/reopening visual studio and restarts but still not appearing.  Has anyone else had this?

Comment: Try running `devenv /setup`

Comment: Nope made no difference

Comment: What framework version is selected in the New Project wizard? Do your vsixs support that framework version?